# PHP Return 'weird value' to javascript function for some IDs

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Im trying to send a values of "customer ID" to javascript function when I clicked any checkbox of customer's name.

It worked fine for most of the IDs, but some of the ID return a **'weird number'** and im sure that's not a number which come from my database(json), more like just a random number.

**Pict 1 is the correct output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4tIc.png

**Pict 2 is the wrong output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEaIY.png

There's the code of the checkbox that will do passing the variable into the javascript function(checkFunction) :

Checkbox that return "customer ID" to javascript **function (checkFunction(check, no))**

```
<tbody>
  <?php for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row"><input id="<?php echo $i; ?>" type="checkbox" 
onclick="checkFunction(<?php echo $json1[$i]['nik'];?>,
<?php echo $i; ?>,
<?php echo $json1[$i]['verify']; ?>)" >
</td>
      <td><?php echo trim($json1[$i]['nik']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $json1[$i]['nama']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
  </tbody>
```

Here's the javascript function that will alert the length of **customer ID** and the ID (*ps : Please don't mind the if else condition because the ID did show fine with that condition too)

```
function checkFunction(check,no) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(no);
  var nik = check;
var verify = 1;
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
            if(nik.toString().length==5){ 
                alert(nik.toString().length + " " + nik + " " + verify);
            }
            else if(nik.toString().length==6){ 
                alert(nik.toString().length + " " + nik + " " + verify);
            }
            else if(nik.toString().length==7){ 
                alert(nik.toString().length + " " + nik + " " + verify);
            }

  }
```

Even some of the IDs that below the **"0144214  DIRHAM"** customer worked fine
(I mean the error do skipping, and i cant find any different of the customer ID which would cause the error)

Sorry for my bad english and thanks

Comment: also in general try not to do this whenever possible. Use PHP to make an API that is consumed by the front end via JSON objects. There are plenty of tutorials about this that you can look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0144214 is valid octal, so is interpreted as 51340 decimal, on the other hand, 0143439 is not valid octal, so is interpreted as 143439

Comment: It solved!!

so I just did convert the oct to string as you said, like 
octdec(decoct($json1[$i]['nik']))
and it worked fine
Thank you so much

Comment: @CarinaNatalia that conversion doesn’t make much sense; all you really had to do was include quotes in the output you are generating, so that JS sees `'0123'` instead of `0123`: `onclick="checkFunction('<?php echo $json1[$i]['nik'];?>',…`